# XCode / AppStore - product name and project name

Tags: ios, xcode

I tried to change my project name by following the many examples found on SO but it gives me a linker error that I was unable to fix. Instead, I decided to only change the target name and the product name.

My question is, is this enough to make sure nowhere in the AppStore my old project name will appear? When I run on a device, I can see "Running [NEW APPNAME] on iPhone". Is this a good sign that all is fine?

Comment: A single project contains multiple targets, most of which are not released.  The name of app is defined by the bundle id and the product (not project) name.

Comment: Found out that I had to change the target name to be able to change the product name. I find all of this very confusing to be honest.

Comment: That doesn't sound right.  Just setting the Product Name in the Build Settings will be enough.  However you will probably want to rename the target anyway, in order to main some consistency.